# Implement CRC algorithm from equation

Tags: equation, crc, crc16

I'm dealing with a device which say to use this 16 bit cyclic redundancy check:

```
CCITT CRC-16 with polynomial x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + x^1
```

I looked for an implementation of such algorithm, but I did find only ones with the last term of the equation equal to `1` (i.e. `x^0`) instead of `x^1`, like [this one](http://www.eagleairaust.com.au/code/crc16.htm) or [this](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__crc.html#ga1c1d3ad875310cbc58000e24d981ad20).

I was going to implement the algorithm by myself, when I realized I don't know how to start. How is it supposed to develop a CRC calculation starting from an equation?

Comment: That's a typo. The CCITT CRC-16 polynomial is x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PDF file explains the subject: [hackersdelight.org/crc.pdf](http://www.hackersdelight.org/crc.pdf).

I also recommend Computer Networks by Andrew Tanenbaum, as it has a chapter on the CRC algorithm.

Finally, I would double-check to see that your device does in fact implement that form of CRC as opposed to the standard one. It might just be a typo.

Comment: Thanks, your answer do fit for the general meaning of the question, although the equation was wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are correct and the polynomial is wrong.  A proper CRC polynomial must always have a 1 term.  The CCITT CRC-16 polynomial is x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1 as noted by @guga, or 0x1021 in bit form (which leaves off the x^16).  See this [catalog of 16-bit CRCs](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm).

The information there also provides the other key information you need besides the polynomial.  Specifically:

```
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0x1d0f refin=false refout=false xorout=0x0000 check=0xe5cc
```

which means that the CRC is not bit-reflected, it is initialized with `0x1d0f`, and the result is not excusive-ored with anything.  So the CCITT CRC of no bytes is `0x1d0f`.  It also provides a check value on the nine-byte string of ASCII digits "123456789", `0xe5cc`.  You should use that to check your implementation.

[Ross Williams guide](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) will tell you all you need to know about implementing CRCs.

Comment: Clear explanation. Thank you for the useful informations and resources as well!